# Wildcard lithium routing

Tags: lithium

I want to route something like this:
    http://myapp.com/mycontroller/...?x=...

where everything after mycontroller is unknown. I dont know the path and i dont know any of the parameters. After routing the path and parameters should appear as one variable.

```
// route in routes.php
Router::connect('/mycontroller/*', 'Mycontroller::index');

// the index function of Mycontroller class
public function index($pathWithParameters) {
    print_r($pathWithParameters); // something like: 'hello/world?name=mewel&id=123
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Router::connect('/mycontroller/{:args}', 'Mycontroller::index');
```

then, from your controller, check `$this->request->params`, and `$this->request->query`

NB: you can use `func_get_args()` in your controller as well. Take a look to default PagesController for an example

Comment: you can use func_get_args() in your controller as well. Take a look to default PagesController for an example